# iOS BLE Two Way Communication

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm very new to swift and BLE. I'm wondering if two-way communication is possible with BLE in iOS? I see on the delegate method,

```
optional func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
       didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, 
                   error: Error?)
```

you can get a handle on 'characteristic' which has a method 'setValue'. Can you update this value and receive the event on the peripheral side?

Ultimately, I want the peripheral side (advertising/beacon side) to know when its characteristic was read and some information can be passed back to it to let the user know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two-way communication with BLE by having side that establishes the connection send data using `setValue` (into some attribute) and the side running the GATT server send data using "indications" or "notifications" on some other attribute.

If you have complete control over the code on the peripheral side than I think you can have it do things on each read of an attribute.  There's no inherent way in the standard to be notified on a read, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a general BLE thing and not a iOS problem. When you read about BLE communication in the web you will read the words Client and Server side which indicates which "side" ist advertising a value (server) and which is receiving it (client).

Furthermore you can create characteristics with different properties e.g. read, write, notify. 
What I suggest is having a characteristic which notifies the client side about new values and every time the `didUpdateValueFor characteristic` method is called you write the information you want the server to receive in this characteristic.

E.g. having the characteristic `notifyMe` with properties read, notify and the characteristic `myAnswer` with a write only property.